# How can I decipher the phrase "On en était où?"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, verbes

So, “*en*” is an *adverbial pronoun* which is used to replace “de + nom”. But what **noun** does it replace in the mentioned phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*En*, *y* and the reflexive pronouns are often used in a way which is not analyzable to modify the meaning of verbs (phrasal verbs in English are doing the same thing with prepositions).  If the meaning of a sentence using these pronoun isn't clear it can be such use.

It is the case with *être*.  There are several meanings associated with *en être*, in some of them *en* is still analyzable, it isn't the case here when *en être* means being at some step in an evolution or progression.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that in this case `en` doesn't replace `de + nom` construction? If so, it might be the similar use, like with the phrase `s'en aller`, for example, right?

Comment: Note that in Brittany (and maybe elsewhere, but with people around France from Paris or the South, it seems that's only there), we often use « se Rendre » instead of « être » in this sentence. Ex.: « On est rendu où ? » for « On en est  où ? », using the same change of word/meaning for « aller/être à un endroit » and « se rendre à ».

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your comment! Maybe you could clarify my last doubts about this phrase. So, in this construction `en être` doesn't replace `de + nom`, does it?

Comment: @jFrenetic, _en_ doesn't replace anything (or at least current speakers aren't conscious of what it refer to, it probably started to refer to something) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you can think of *en* as standing for the thing that was in progress.

> Où était-on *dans notre conversation* ?
>
> Où *en* était-on ?

However, as Un francophone points out, this is pretty much a fixed phrase. I couldn't tell if the grammatical construction really originates in this.

The good news is, once you know it, French actually makes it clearer than the more versatile English *where were we ?* ;)

Answer (score -1):

"On en était où" est familier et peu correct.

Il faudrait dire "Où en étions-nous".

Quant à "où en était-on" c'est tellement laid phonétiquement qu'il faut le bannir, sans parler du phonème grotesque de la fin de la locution.

Comment: Merci, mais ce n'est pas la réponse à mon question.