# What does the "en" in "Qu'en est-il de" refer to?

Tags: sens, expressions

When I first saw this expression, I attempted to read it as:

> *What is it of?* or *What is it about?*

When I checked the definitions given to me by ReversoContext ([here](https://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/Qu%27en+est-il+de) and Linguee ([here](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=qu%27en%20est-il%20de&cw=467)), it turns out I was somehow on the right path.

But still I have some confusion regarding the *en* found within the expression. What does it refer to, since I think that it's the adverbial pronoun *en*?

For example:

> Qu'en est-il de ses devoirs ?

To me, I think this question is asking about the state of his homework or rather, what's the news or what's up with it. Does the *en* in that *Qu'en est-il de* refer to the state or the news (des nouvelles ?) or is it something else?

---

On a side note, does an *en être* exist? If so, would it be connected to this expression?

Comment: *En être* you will find in a dictionary.  Is there more context here, like the rest of the sentence? Related https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25533/1893 and https://french.stackexchange.com/q/42281/1893

Comment: I just added some additional info to my question since I couldn't find the article in which I first found the expression. And the links you gave were helpful, thank you.

Comment: The expression "qu'en est-il de [x]" translates to: what about So: What about his homework?. Or: Has he done his homework? in some contexts. The en refers to what the subject matter is after the preposition de.

Answer (score 1):

*Qu'en est-il de ses devoirs ?* is a formal way to say "What about his/her homework?" / "What is the status of their homework?"

Casual ones could be, depending on the intended meaning / the context:

- *Ça en est où, ses devoirs ?*
- *Ils en sont où, ses devoirs ?*
- *Ça se passe comment, ses devoirs ?*
- *Ça se passe comment, avec ses devoirs ?*
- *Ça se passe comment, pour ses devoirs ?*

or simply

- *Et ses devoirs ?*

***En*** refers to the degree of progress of something that is evolving like with *How far along is their homework?*

***En être*** very much exists and is documented in dictionaries, e.g. [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) **III.** **B-** **6.** **e)**

Without any complement (e.g. *Il en est* or *J'en suis*), *En être* means to belong to some undisclosed group.

With a complement, it's like you example.

There is also ***en être à***, a shorter way to say *en être réduit à*:

- *Je suis à faire de la figuration* → "I'm reduced to being an extra."

Answer (score -2):

1/ "En" is the personal pronoun and cannot be an "adverbial pronoun".

> ([Kalmbach-Grammaire](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/pron-il.html#257)) Le pronom *y* à valeur d’adverbe
>
> Quand le pronom *y* sert d’adverbe spatial polyvalent, il se comporte comme les adverbes devant, derrière, en-dessous etc. (c’est le seul cas où *y* puisse réellement être défini comme un adverbe et où survive le sens du latin ibi) :
>
> Il aimait la Laponie en hiver. Le climat y [= en Laponie] est plus sec que dans le sud
> ■ J’ai rangé le fouillis derrière la remise. J’y [= derrière la remise] ai trouvé une vieille canne de mon grand-père
> ■ Nous allons régulièrement en Vendée en été. Nous y [= en Vendée] avons des amis
> ■ Je connais un peu Monaco, nous y [= à Monaco] avons visité le musée océanographique.
>
> Le pronom *en*, contrairement à *y*, ne peut pas se substituer à un nom en fonction de complément de phrase (CdP) [user LPH: also called "complément circonstanciel"]. Le CdP doit être repris par un adverbe, comparer :
>
> ■ Il est rentré de la montagne hier. → Il en est rentré hier. (*en* = CVP) [user LPH: "complément de verbe prépositionnel"] MAIS :
> ■ De la montagne, on voyait bien la ville. → De là-bas, on voyait bien la ville.
>
> La raison pour laquelle en ne peut pas fonctionner comme pronom-adverbe à valeur spatiale, c’est qu’il s’utilise aussi, entre autres, en fonction de complément du nom, pour marquer le possesseur non animé. Si on faisait la transformation *de la montagne, on voyait bien le port→ on en voyait bien le port*, le pronom en renverrait au groupe nominal complément *de port (?le port de la montagne)*, comme dans l’exemple suivant :
>
> ■  Nous avons survolé Rotterdam en avion. On en voyait bien le port.  [en renvoie de façon univoque à Rotterdam, et non pas à de l’avion.]

2/ I think that both Reverso and Linguee provide a useful translation. Other translations to be found in [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/Qu%27en%20est-il) will also be useful.

> **Qu'en est-il ?** expression idiomatique (Où est-ce que ça en est ?) [user LPH: "en" in this rendering is not the same as in "qu'en est-il". Moreover, this rendering shifts the meaning toward the idea that the inquiry is which  stage of progression is being under way, and this is only a very particular cas of "what is the situation". So, is not relevant, in my opinion.]
>
> How do things stand? expression
> What's the situation? expression
> (informal, figurative) What's the score? expression

3/ We see in "2/" that "qu'en est-il" is an idiom (expression idiomatique). Grammatically, it is useless trying to analyse "en".
Similarly, "qu'en est-il de XXX" is an idiom for all XXXX. The rendering would be "où est-ce que XXX en est".

Do not confuse this use of "en" with that in "[TLFI, **section 2 III.B.6.e)**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre)"; under this heading we have the following possibilities:

- α) [Pour exprimer la qualité d'élément d'un groupe]
- β) [Pour marquer un moment ou une étape dans le déroulement ou l'évolution de quelque chose].

This use has certainly nothing to do with "belonging to a group"; the only possible question can be "En est-il ?"; (*example: — Il n'était pas du complot. — Si, il en était. — En était-il ?*). There is not either any matter of determination of a stage because the question for this branch is typically "Où en est/êtes/sont/… ?, and typically the answer requires the preposition "à" (*examples: il en est **à** ses débuts — nous en somme **à** l'étude du squellette — ils en sont **à** la troisième année*).